# OwinOAuthProviders RefreshToken flow

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, owin, asp.net-mvc-5, katana

I'm building a OwinOAuth (Oauth2) provider for my company to contribute here-https://github.com/TerribleDev/OwinOAuthProviders

The challenge I'm facing is that my company generates the refresh token too along with access token and provides the expiry time for both access token and refresh token. Access token expiry is set to 1hr and using Refresh token I can refresh access tokens again and again for 100 days.

Any implementations that I have seen create a RefreshTokenProvider which I don't need as my company already sends me that. The question I have here is this-
In the AuthenticationHandler class, since tokens are in memory and not saved anywhere and Oauth tokens are always generated by default, I'm not sure where the call/logic to get access tokens based on Refresh Tokens should be done.

Do I need to create a persistent store for all returned tokens and expiry and then match expiry to make a call to RefreshTokenHandler(grant_type=refresh_token) instead of AuthenticationHandler(grant_type=authorization_code) based on that?

I'm really confused here and any help with the implementation is appreciated.

EDIT-1
I have replaced my provider's name with Hidden everywhere. 
Adding code for the HiddenAuthenticationHandler.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.Owin.Logging;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Owin.Security.Providers.Hidden.Provider;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Net;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;

namespace Owin.Security.Providers.Hidden
{
    public class HiddenAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<HiddenAuthenticationOptions>
{
    private const string XmlSchemaString = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string";
    private const string AuthorizationEndPoint = "https://appcenter.Hidden.com/connect/oauth2";
    private const string TokenEndpoint = "https://oauth.platform.Hidden.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer";
    private const string UserInfoEndpoint = "https://sandbox-accounts.platform.Hidden.com/v1/openid_connect/userinfo";//"https://accounts.Hidden.com/v1/openid_connect/userinfo";//Nimisha
    private const string RevokeEndpoint = "https://developer.api.Hidden.com/v2/oauth2/tokens/revoke";//Nimisha
    private const string JWKSEndpoint = "https://oauth.platform.Hidden.com/op/v1/jwks";//Nimisha
    private const string IssuerEndpoint = "https://oauth.platform.Hidden.com/op/v1";//Nimisha
    private const string DiscoveryEndpoint = "https://developer.Hidden.com/.well-known/openid_configuration";//Nimisha


    private static string refreshToken;
    private static string refreshTokenExpiresIn;
    private static string tokenType;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public HiddenAuthenticationHandler(HttpClient httpClient, ILogger logger)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
        _logger = logger;
    }
    //public async Task GrantRefreshToken(OAuthGrantRefreshTokenContext context)
    //{
    //    var originalClient = context.Ticket.Properties.Dictionary["as:client_id"];
    //    var currentClient = context.ClientId;

    //    if (originalClient != currentClient)
    //    {
    //        context.SetError("invalid_clientId", "Refresh token is issued to a different clientId.");
    //        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    //    }

    //    // Change auth ticket for refresh token requests
    //    var newIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Ticket.Identity);
    //    newIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("newClaim", "newValue"));

    //    var newTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(newIdentity, context.Ticket.Properties);
    //    context.Validated(newTicket);

    //    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    //}

    public async Task<AuthenticationTicket> RefreshTokenAsync()
    {

        AuthenticationProperties properties = null;

        // OAuth2 10.12 CSRF
        if (!ValidateCorrelationId(properties, _logger))
        {
            return new AuthenticationTicket(null, properties);
        }

        //var requestPrefix = Request.Scheme + "://" + Request.Host;
        ////var redirectUri = requestPrefix + Request.PathBase + Options.CallbackPath;
        //var redirectUri = "https://be97d742.ngrok.io/signin-Hidden";

        // Build up the body for the token request
        var body = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "refresh_token"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("refresh_token", refreshToken)
            };

        // Request the token
        var refreshTokenResponse =
            await _httpClient.PostAsync(TokenEndpoint, new FormUrlEncodedContent(body));
        refreshTokenResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var text = await refreshTokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        // Deserializes the token response
        dynamic response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(text);
        var accessToken = (string)response.access_token;
        var expires = (string)response.expires_in;
        //string refreshToken = null;
        refreshToken = (string)response.refresh_token;
        refreshTokenExpiresIn = (string)response.x_refresh_token_expires_in;
        tokenType = (string)response.token_type;

        return new AuthenticationTicket(null, properties);
    }


    protected override async Task<AuthenticationTicket> AuthenticateCoreAsync()
    {
        AuthenticationProperties properties = null;

        try
        {
            string code = null;
            string state = null;

            var query = Request.Query;
            var values = query.GetValues("code");
            if (values != null && values.Count == 1)
            {
                code = values[0];
            }
            values = query.GetValues("state");
            if (values != null && values.Count == 1)
            {
                state = values[0];
            }

            properties = Options.StateDataFormat.Unprotect(state);
            if (properties == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            // OAuth2 10.12 CSRF
            if (!ValidateCorrelationId(properties, _logger))
            {
                return new AuthenticationTicket(null, properties);
            }

            var requestPrefix = Request.Scheme + "://" + Request.Host;
            //var redirectUri = requestPrefix + Request.PathBase + Options.CallbackPath;
            var redirectUri = "https://be97d742.ngrok.io/signin-Hidden";

            // Build up the body for the token request
            var body = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "authorization_code"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", code),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri", redirectUri),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", Options.ClientId),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", Options.ClientSecret)
            };

            // Request the token
            var tokenResponse =
                await _httpClient.PostAsync(TokenEndpoint, new FormUrlEncodedContent(body));
            tokenResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var text = await tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            // Deserializes the token response
            dynamic response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(text);
            var accessToken = (string)response.access_token;
            var expires = (string)response.expires_in;
            //string refreshToken = null; //Nimisha
            refreshToken = (string)response.refresh_token;
            refreshTokenExpiresIn = (string)response.x_refresh_token_expires_in;
            tokenType = (string)response.token_type;

            // Get the Hidden user
            var userRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, Options.Endpoints.UserInfoEndpoint );
            userRequest.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            userRequest.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

            var userResponse = await _httpClient.SendAsync(userRequest, Request.CallCancelled);
            userResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            text = await userResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


            var user = JObject.Parse(text);


            var context = new HiddenAuthenticatedContext(Context, user, accessToken, expires, refreshToken, refreshTokenExpiresIn, tokenType)
            {
                Identity = new ClaimsIdentity(
                    Options.AuthenticationType,
                    ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType,
                    ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType)
            };
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Sub))
            {
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, context.Sub, XmlSchemaString, Options.AuthenticationType));
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.GivenName))
            {
                string Name = "";
                Name = context.GivenName;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.FamilyName))
                {
                    Name = Name +" " + context.FamilyName;
                }
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, Name, XmlSchemaString, Options.AuthenticationType));
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:Hidden:name", Name, XmlSchemaString, Options.AuthenticationType));

            }
            if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Email)) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.EmailVerified)))
            {
                if (String.Equals(context.EmailVerified, "true"))
                {
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, context.Email, XmlSchemaString, Options.AuthenticationType));

                }
            }
            if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.PhoneNumber)) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.PhoneNumberVerified)))
            {
                if (String.Equals(context.PhoneNumberVerified, "true"))
                {
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.MobilePhone, context.Email, XmlSchemaString, Options.AuthenticationType));

                }
            }



            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.StreetAddress))
            {
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, context.StreetAddress, XmlSchemaString, Options.AuthenticationType));
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Locality))
            {
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, context.Locality, XmlSchemaString, Options.AuthenticationType));
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Region))
            {
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, context.Locality, XmlSchemaString, Options.AuthenticationType));
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.PostalCode))
            {
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, context.Locality, XmlSchemaString, Options.AuthenticationType));
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Country))
            {
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, context.Locality, XmlSchemaString, Options.AuthenticationType));
            }

            context.Properties = properties;

            await Options.Provider.Authenticated(context);

            return new AuthenticationTicket(context.Identity, context.Properties);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.WriteError(ex.Message);
        }
        return new AuthenticationTicket(null, properties);
    }

    protected override Task ApplyResponseChallengeAsync()//Nimisha-1
    {
        if (Response.StatusCode != 401)
        {
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        //If Response is 401 then check here based on saved Expiration duration for token and refreshtoken and then make either Refresh Token call or Access Token call
        //if(SavedTokenExpiryTime is not null and is >=DateTime.Now) then call RefreshToken api call 
        //or
        //Call below



        var challenge = Helper.LookupChallenge(Options.AuthenticationType, Options.AuthenticationMode);

        if (challenge == null) return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        var baseUri =
            Request.Scheme +
            Uri.SchemeDelimiter +
            Request.Host +
            Request.PathBase;

        var currentUri =
            baseUri +
            Request.Path +
            Request.QueryString;

        //var redirectUri =
        //    baseUri +
        //    Options.CallbackPath;//Nimisha check callback path
        var redirectUri = "https://be97d742.ngrok.io/signin-Hidden";

        var properties = challenge.Properties;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(properties.RedirectUri))
        {
            properties.RedirectUri = currentUri;
        }

        // OAuth2 10.12 CSRF
        GenerateCorrelationId(properties);

        // comma separated
        var scope = string.Join(" ", Options.Scope);

        var state = Options.StateDataFormat.Protect(properties);

        //Nimisha //"https://appcenter.Hidden.com/connect/oauth2" + //Nimisha check
        var authorizationEndpoint =              
            Options.Endpoints.AuthorizationEndpoint+
            "?client_id=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(Options.ClientId) +
            "&response_type=code" +
            "&scope=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(scope) +
            "&redirect_uri=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(redirectUri) +
            "&state=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(state);


        Response.Redirect(authorizationEndpoint);

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public override async Task<bool> InvokeAsync()
    {
        return await InvokeReplyPathAsync();
    }

    private async Task<bool> InvokeReplyPathAsync()
    {
        if (!Options.CallbackPath.HasValue || Options.CallbackPath != Request.Path) return false;
        // TODO: error responses


        var ticket = await AuthenticateAsync();
        if (ticket == null)
        {
            _logger.WriteWarning("Invalid return state, unable to redirect.");
            Response.StatusCode = 500;
            return true;
        }

        var context = new HiddenReturnEndpointContext(Context, ticket)
        {
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = Options.SignInAsAuthenticationType,
            RedirectUri = ticket.Properties.RedirectUri
        };

        await Options.Provider.ReturnEndpoint(context);

        if (context.SignInAsAuthenticationType != null &&
            context.Identity != null)
        {
            var grantIdentity = context.Identity;
            if (!string.Equals(grantIdentity.AuthenticationType, context.SignInAsAuthenticationType, StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                grantIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(grantIdentity.Claims, context.SignInAsAuthenticationType, grantIdentity.NameClaimType, grantIdentity.RoleClaimType);
            }
            Context.Authentication.SignIn(context.Properties, grantIdentity);
        }

        if (context.IsRequestCompleted || context.RedirectUri == null) return context.IsRequestCompleted;
        var redirectUri = context.RedirectUri;
        if (context.Identity == null)
        {
            // add a redirect hint that sign-in failed in some way
            redirectUri = WebUtilities.AddQueryString(redirectUri, "error", "access_denied");
        }
        Response.Redirect(redirectUri);
        context.RequestCompleted();

        return context.IsRequestCompleted;
    }




}
}
```

Comment: Show us your code. It's easier to understand that way.

Comment: Added the code with my understanding of where the refresh token handling needs to take place. It may or may not be correct.

Comment: Have you looked at Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider

Comment: I did look into it. Does it mean I need to have an Custom AuthorizationServer as well along with the Identity management using Owin?

Comment: I am not an expert at this and the terminology confuses the hell out of me but you just have to derive from OUthAuthorizationServerProvider class and override relevant methods to wire your tokens which could be coming from wherever you want and register it with owin. There is no server as such. It's quite simple actually, you should look at some samples and it will be quite clear

Comment: Yes, I did. It requires you to build a store to save the tokens first and that is what I wanted to avoid. It is indeed confusing because you have examples of IdentityServer , Authorization Server and then Resource Server all over the place. But there is just this one Angular sample app  https://github.com/tjoudeh/AngularJSAuthentication which has everything.

Comment: Frankly I am so scared of this framework now that understanding the Angular piece too is making me go crazy. Thanks for your help though

Comment: Each time an access token is requested, a refresh token is added. Is this the same refresh token or a new one?